# ggboxplot add.params shape parameter not working

Tags: r, shapes, ggpubr

The shape parameter in the ggpubr::ggboxplot add.params argument does not respond to the value given. Here is an example:

```
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8, 
          add="dotplot", add.params=list(color="blue", shape=1))
```

I expect a circle instead of a filled dot when using shape=1. I tried several other values and the shape is always shown as a solid dot. How to get it to respond to the parameter value?

[image]

Comment: I believe that `ggpubr::ggdotplot` uses the `geom_dotplot` geom from `ggplot2`, which does not use the `shape` parameter.  See `?ggdotplot` and `?geom_dotplot`.

Comment: Thanks @neilfws. This could be the reason. It will explain why `shape` works in `add="jitter"`. But I wonder why it doesn't work in `add="point"`? `geom_point` should take `shape`, right? And what does it use for `add="mean"`? `shape` also doesn't work for it.

Comment: I can't answer those questions, but my personal opinion of `ggpubr` is that it confuses new users more than it helps. Under the hood it's using `ggplot2` but it tries to hide things from the user, which makes it difficult to troubleshoot when issues arise. I think new users would be better served learning how to use `ggplot2`.

Comment: Thanks @neilfws. You helped me to make a decision on which package to use☺